# What kind of Threads dose apache process include?

Tags: apache

I use Apache for windows.

My Windows resource monitor shows 5 threads in httpd.exe although I set 1 for ThreadsParCild directive in httpd.conf.

I know 1 of the thread must be worker thread as I set.

Then what are another 4 threads for?. Are tye somthing idling thread?

Comment: [MinSpareServers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html#minspareservers). Prefork also does not use threads, it uses processes which are much more expensive.

Comment: The default for Windows appears to be [mpm_winnt](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_winnt.html) (which does use threading), not prefork, though. IANA